# Использовать ли seo на приватных страницах

Tags: seo, оптимизация-сайтов, поисковая-оптимизация

В случае если страницы, которые можент видеть незарегестрированный пользователь, ограничены только : главной (`index`) а также страницами восстановления пароля и активации (`которые являются динамическими и в зависимости от параметра либо отобразят соответсвующую форму, либо скажут что ссылка неактивна`) то нужно ли проводить seo оптимизацию метатегов приватных страниц и на что это влияет ? Нужно ли указывать приватные страницы в sitemap.xml ? Ведь по идеи поисковые роботы смогут `увидеть` только главную страницу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще приватные страницы прописываются в robots.txt. 
Мы запрещаем ботам индексировать их. 
Приватные страницы не будут индексироваться, соотв. СЕО оптимизация для них и не нужна.

Пример для Wordpress

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/ # Админка
Disallow: /wp-login.php # Страница авторизации и регистрации, там же и восстановление доступа
```